# Product of disjoint cycles agrees with each factor on its support

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-cycles

**Claim.** Let $(\zeta_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a family of cycles of a finite set E whose supports are pairwise disjoint. Let $\sigma=\Pi_{i\in I}\zeta_i$. Then $\sigma(x)=\zeta_i(x)$ for $x\in supp(\zeta_i)$ and $i\in I$.

Note that $supp(\zeta_i)=\{x\in E\ |\ \zeta_i(x)\ne x\}$.

**My attempt:**

I know that, for $i\in I$ and $x\in supp(\zeta_i)$, $\zeta_i(x)\in supp(\zeta_i)$; therefore, $\zeta_i(x)\notin supp(\zeta_j)$ for $j\ne i$. Hence, $\zeta_j\zeta_i(x)=\zeta_i(x)$ for $j\ne i$. I also know that $\zeta_i\zeta_j=\zeta_j\zeta_i$ for $i,j\in I$.

I can see why this equality holds. I just don't know how to prove it.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your question about getting an idea of the proof or about formalizing it? In the former case, the answer is very simple: You want to prove that $\sigma$ and $\prod\limits_{i\in I} \zeta_i$ (by the way, I hope you know why this product is well-defined?) are identical; it clearly suffices to show that $\sigma\left(x\right) = \left(\prod\limits_{i\in I} \zeta_i\right)\left(x\right)$ for each $x \in E$. So fix $x \in E$. Then there is at most one $i \in I$ such that $x \in \operatorname{supp}\left(\zeta_i\right)$. Moreover, if we denote this $i$ by $j$, then ...

Comment: ... $\zeta_j\left(x\right)$ is still in $\operatorname{supp}\left(\zeta_j\right)$ and in no other $\operatorname{supp}\left(\zeta_i\right)$. Does this help?

Comment: For your formalist needs (if any), see the proofs of Lemma 7.101 and Lemma 7.102 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 2019-01-10](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). Note that you don't need to know that the $\zeta_i$ are cycles; they can be any maps from $E$ to $E$.

Comment: I would like to write a rigorous the proof; informally, I understand what is going in. I will look over your notes. Thank you

Comment: (Actually, my last sentence was wrong: The $\zeta_i$ can be any **permutations** of $E$, not arbitrary maps from $E$ to $E$. It is a nice exercise in carefulness to see why.)